# Keyword search using query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a simple question, so I'll keep it short:

If I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE * = ?
```

Will this work as a search function? Assuming each row on the table keywords had 10 or 20 "keywords," would this find all rows that had `?` in them?

Essentially, can an asterisk be used for any value in an SQL query?

UPDATE:
The table I was planning was like this:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------
|ID |keyword1 |keyword2 |keyword3 |keyword4 |keyword5 |
 -----------------------------------------------------
|5  |blablaa2 |blablaa3 |bla blaa4|bl abla?5| blablaa6|
 -----------------------------------------------------
```

Due to concerns about "maintenance and performance" I'm considering this:

```
------------
|ID|Keyword|
|5 |blablaa|
|3 |blablaa|
|5 |blablaa|
|2 |blablaa|
|1 |blablaa|
------------
```

Then my SQL query would be like:

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyword = ?
```

On both, `ID` would be referenced in another table, and keywords would be used primarily for searching that table.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: No.  You cannot do wildcards for column or table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the answer is no, but if you'll change it to:

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE column_name LIKE '%?%'
```

it [*should work*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7d86/1).

Second, it's not clear from your question how is the table constructed. If it's something like:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------
|column1 |column2 |column3 |column4 |column5 |column6 |
 -----------------------------------------------------
|blablaa1|blablaa2|blablaa3|blablaa4|blabla?5|blablaa6|
 -----------------------------------------------------
...
```

then the answer I wrote in before won't work and the design is not good and should be replaced with one keyword per row. Another approach would be to query the table as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE column1 LIKE '%?%' OR 
column2 LIKE '%?%' OR 
column3 LIKE '%?%' OR 
...
```

but, as I just mentioned, this is NOT a good way to construct your table and you'd better think how to re-design it for better performance & maintenance.

Comment: He doesn't necessarily have a column called keyword. I think he's trying to search every column for a string.

Comment: @ktm5124 I agree, this is why I added the second paragraph.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with sqlfiddle, never seen that before, cool. Why is that a bad way to construct a table? And the table I was planning was like this:

(couldn't display here, check the question update.)

With '5' being referenced on another table.

Comment: Like I wrote, it's bad to construct it this way due to a) maintenance: say, for example you need to construct another keyword table and you'll do it exactly like this again, now using both tables will require an ugly join. Try to scale it to 4-5 tables and you got yourself a maintenance nightmare. And b) performance - read about `table indexing` to see why constructing it this way interferes with DB optimization

Answer (score 1):

Not in MySQL. You can test it on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d394/1.

I have never seen people use wildcards for column names. I doubt there's any RDBMS that allows it.

What you can do is create a table called keywords that lists the keywords for every row in a table. You can do an inner join on that table and search for KEYWORD=?.